# HTML Link to another page does not execute javascript or load CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink

I have several HTML pages running Javascript and JQuery Mobile, and I want to link to them from another HTML page. My link is setup as:

```
<a href="hours.html">Hours</a>
```

and the linking page and the pages being linked to are in the same directory. However, when I access the page through this link, the JQuery Mobile theme is loaded, but any additional CSS changes or any Javascript code doesn't execute. I have several methods set to run on startup, but none execute, not even a simple alert.

When I attempt to access the page directly, everything applies properly and my code executes, but when I try to access it through my HTML link, none of it works. Is there something I am forgetting?

Thanks!

Edit: None of the code is working for any link I link to. Even a simple:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("Hello world");
});
```

does not work. I have this added into the other HTML page as:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Hours</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">

  <link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.1/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js'></script>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.1/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert("Hello world");
    });
  </script>
  <style type="text/css">
    * { 
        font-family: "Celeste Mobi Pro", Celeste, serif;
    }
  </style>
</head>
```

Neither the CSS font change nor the startup alert works. I've tried this on other HTML pages, so I think it might be the server I'm hosting it on, but I'm not sure.

Second Edit: I just tested it locally, and it works. I'm fairly certain it's the server right now, is there anything I should check?

Third Edit: I've been using the Chrome console to look at the javascript source on the pages being linked to. I have all scripts added through script tags in the head, but for some reason, none of those appear. Rather, the contents of the script tags are those from the page linking to them (and yes, I'm making sure that I'm checking the  for the new page, not the old page). When I refresh the page, however, it updates and it seems to work.

Comment: Is this being developed on localhost or external site?  If it were me, I would examine things in Firebug and see exactly where it is looking for your resources.

Comment: Add the code that is not working please

Comment: Added to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

According to every data that you provide us, what you are telling us should work. There's no flaw in it.

The only possible error that you may encounter may be that you are using two differents `hours.html`, and accessing the wrong one through your link.